# Passing prop to child element - react

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I'm attempting to pass 'backgroundColor' as a prop from one file to another. However, the background color isn't changing. Please take a look at the code below.

Line Component:

```
const Line = (backgroundColor) => {
    return(
        <div className="line-wrap">
            <div className="line" style={{backgroundColor: backgroundColor}}></div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Start typing.."></input>
          </div>

    )
}
```

Other File:

```
    const addLine = () => {
    updateLines((prevArray) => [...prevArray, "New Line"]);
    };

      {lines.map((line, i) => {
            const colors = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "green", "grey"];
            let randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
            console.log(randomColor);
            return <Line key={i} backgroundColor={randomColor} />;
          })}
```

Comment: ```const Line = (backgroundColor) => {``` or ```const Line = ({backgroundColor}) => {```. It's possible that you aren't de-structuring the props.

Comment: @NeoWang Thank you, the second option works and the colours change. However, the existing lines also change background colour too. How do I randomise only the background colour of the new lines which appear?

Comment: I think you could Keep an array with the values. If the index doesn't line up, update the array.

Comment: Make sure to remove any unused elements after each update; something you would do with useEffect.